# wouldn't we all?

Tags: phrase-meaning

A) That was fantastic and I love to be there.

B) Ah, ***wouldn't we all*** ?

To be honest as an intermediate English learner this answer doesn't make sense to me.
would you please explain a bit and make it clear that what is meant here and when it is used.

Answer (score 5):

I assume ***A*** is a person who is saying the first line, and ***B*** is a person who is saying the second line. I've changed it somewhat below:

> Andrea: "I would love to live in beautiful Tuscany."
>
> Bobby: "Wouldn't we all?"

Notice that Andrea is using the modal verb "would," and Bobby responds also with the modal "would not." Bobby cannot say ***Wouldn't we all?*** unless Andrea has used "would."

***Wouldn't we all?*** is a set phrase that is short for, ***Wouldn't we all love to live in Tuscany?*** You can translate it to mean, ***Everyone would love to live in Tuscany.*** It's a way of being agreeable with Andrea.

Comment: I would also note that the reply is a rhetorical question.